# Prefixless Palindromes

Tags: code-golf, string, combinatorics

Write a program or function that takes **N**, and **S** and outputs the number of palindromes of length **S** you can build using an alphabet of size **N** such that any prefix of size between **2** and **S-1** is not a palindrome.

For example if **N** were **2** and **S** were **5**

The valid palindromes would be

```
01110
10001
```

And thus the answer would be 2

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes based on their length with fewer bytes being better.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Despite its laconic format, this looks like a valid challenge -- provided that it is neither a dupe nor a question picked somewhere else without permission. At the very least, you'd need to add an [objective primary winning criterion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) such as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). I'd recommend to add some examples and test cases as well.

Comment: @Arnauld It's possible for us to change a off-topic question to a valid challenge (ais523 did that for a few times) but in that case it is obviously not what the OP want. It won't hurt anyway.

Comment: the result isn't infinite ? for N >= 2 : `01111111111111111111111111..0` is a palindrome such that any prefix is not a palindrome

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul of length S.

Comment: @user77149 If you ask it here you will get answers like "Jelly, 15 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//xZLhuILGpOG4iuKBvOKBtOKAmeG5rMKkClLhuZfDh@KCrFP///8z/zQ)"

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//xZLhuILGpOG4igpS4bmXw4figqzEi@KBtOKAmeG5rMKk////M/80)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṗŒḂƤ€Ḋ€Ḅċ1
```

This is a brute-force search over all **n<sup>s</sup>** possible strings.

My results differ from the other answers', but [the solutions my answer counts](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//xZLhuILGpOG4iuG4hD0xCuG5l8OHw5BmR////zP/NQ) seem to be valid.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzulHJz3c0XRsyaOmNQ93dIHJliPdhv///zf@bwoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
lf!tit_IM._T2^SE
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lf%21tit_IM._T2%5ESE&input=5%0A3&debug=0)**

My answer agrees with [Dennis' results](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152225/59487), rather than the Haskell and the Python answers.

#### How it works

```
lf!tit_IM._T2^SE | Full program.

              SE | Grab the second input (E), make an integer range from 1 ... E.
             ^   | And take the Qth Cartesian Power, where Q is the first input.
 f               | Filter by a condition that uses T as a variable.
         ._T     | Take all the prefixes of T...
      _IM        | And for each prefix, check if they're invariant over reversal.
     t           | Take the tail (remove the first element).
    i       2    | Convert from base 2 to integer.
  !t             | Decrement, negate. Note that among the integers, only 0 is falsy.
l                | Take the length of the filtered list.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 19 bytes

```
Lf(=1ḋ↔mS=↔‼hU¡h)πŀ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3ydNw9bw4Y7uR21TcoNtgeSjhj0ZoYcWZmiebzja8P//f6P/pgA) or [view the solutions!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P7c8TcPW8OGO7kdtU3KDbYHko4Y9GaGHFmZonm842vD//3@j/6YA)

#### Explanation

```
Lf(=1ḋ↔mS=↔‼hU¡h)πŀ  -- takes two arguments N S, example: 2 4
                  ŀ  -- range [0..N-1]: [0,1]
                 π   -- all strings of length S: [[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],…,[1,1,1,1]]
 f(             )    -- filter with the following predicate (example with [0,1,1,0]):
              ¡h     --   infinitely times take the head & accumulate in list: [[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1],[0],[],[],…
             U       --   only keep longest prefix with unique elements: [[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1],[0],[]]
           ‼h        --   get rid of last two (apply twice head): [[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1]]
       m             --   map the following
        S=           --     is itself equal to..
          ↔          --     .. itself reversed?
                     --   ↳ [1,0,0]
      ↔              --   reverse: [0,0,1]
     ḋ               --   convert from binary: 1
   =1                --   is it equal to 1: 1
                     -- ↳ [[1,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0]]
L                    -- length: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 129 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
?l=l==reverse l
@n s=sum[1\\p<-iter s(\a=[[e:b]\\e<-[1..n],b<-a])[[]]|and[?p:[not(?q)\\q<-inits p%(2,s-1)]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xCoMwFAB3vyJLQcEItnQpBh3aoeDmmGR4aloCyVOTKBT67U0Fp@OGgxuMAox2GlejiAWNUdt5coF0YXzglu9odZ/UhhnGnNqU84qYpEHimV8tL4WYK6qDcsSnAhjn6tZLIVRFeVkUKPO@oiAzzqX8Ao68nm8cp5DWSybEsqeogyfzKT3nnpaZlDJ2AVxIGGku5Bp/w8vA20f6bOP9g2D1cMhx9gc)